# How can I apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for this problem?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I am confused on how I can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for the following problem:

> A group consists of 8 Students from School A, 7 from school B and 6 from school C. How many ways can a committee of 5 be selected from this group if there must be at least one student from each school ?

My intuition would be to find $$ n(A\cup B \cup C) $$ but the problem is that I don't know how to find the intersections of this set to get the total number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would think that each student is enrolled at exactly one school, so the intersections are empty. This is a counting problem, not an inclusion-exclusion one.

Comment: what means the expression $n(\cdots)$? Sorry if this is common but it is the second time that I see it today.

Comment: @Masacroso I apologize I should have stated it but $n(A \cup B \cup C)$ in my question means the number of elements in A union B union C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Your set $A$ is the number of ways of forming the committee with *nobody* from school $A$, set $B$ is the number of ways of forming the committee with *nobody* from school $B$ and set $C$ is the number of ways of forming the committee with *nobody* from school $C$.

You can use PIE as usual but you need to figure out $n((A\cup B\cup C)')$.

> Note carefully that *my* sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ are *different* from those in the question. In other words: you are *not* done once you have calculated $n(A\cup B\cup C)$, see hint 2 for more details.

Hint 2:

Note that there are $\binom{21}{5}$ *total* committees.

You may notice that the complement of the union is

$$n((A\cup B\cup C)')= \binom{21}{5}- n(A\cup B\cup C)$$

and $n(A)$ is the count for committees formed from students only from schools $B$ and $C$ so

$$n(A)=\binom{13}{5}$$

$n(B)$, $n(C)$ and intersections are also needed to use PIE to find $n(A\cup B\cup C)$.

This is a big hint!

Comment: `n(A) is the count for committees formed from students only from schools B and C` What is $n(A \cup B \cup C)$ then? It's certainly not what @Robert wrote in a previous comment that $n(A \cup B \cup C)$ is.

Comment: No that's right, it is the number of committees with $0$ students from school $A$ *or* $0$ from school $B$ *or* $0$ from school $C$. We want to *exclude* this union from the total since we want at least $1$ student from each school.

Comment: You may want to add that into the answer, especially since it's a different meaning than @Robert's question uses: `n(A∪B∪C) in my question means the number of elements in A union B union C`.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you have to pick a student from each school, which can be done in $8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$ ways. For the rest, you can pick any combination of $2$ from the remaining pool of $8+7+6-3=18\,$ students.